# How do ViewGroups handle background image scaling?

Tags: android, android-drawable

If I have a large image, `somebackground.png` in `drawable-nodpi` and set it to the background of something:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/somebackground"/>
```

Does Android handle efficiently scaling it, using inJustDecodeBounds and whatnot or will it decode the image at its full resolution?

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java

Comment: @pskink From this it appears that it IS indeed scaled automatically, just not the way that one would normally do it, correct?

Comment: yes, its scaled automatically if no gravity is set